# Joomla Upgradation showing error

Tags: joomla3.0

I upgraded joomla but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JSite::execute() in /home/digitec4/public_html/index.php on line 40

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options in order to solve this problem:

1) Upgrade Joomla (if available). You just need to go to your control panel from the administrator sub-site and upgrade.

2) Reinstall Joomla and move your directory structure to the new installation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit only "public_html/jupgrade/libraries/cms/controller" and rename the file of the controller.